# Passing index as a parameter in the python query for elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-net

I have a piece of python query to retrieve data from **elasticsearch**:-

```
es=Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'])
res = es.search(index="index1", doc_type="log",size=1000, from_=0, body={              "query": {
  "match": {
  ....Match condition
  }
 }
}})
```

Is there any way we can pass the index as parameter i.e assign the value of *index1* outside the query and then use it for extracting results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you do not want to hard code the index value.
IF that is the case you can always use format

```
'{0}'.format(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your case you can write like this:

```
res = es.search(index='{0}'.format(index1), doc_type="log",size=1000, from_=0, body={ "query": { "match": { ....Match condition } } }})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for